# Can I add a required param to devise sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Is there any **simple** way of adding a required param for registration on Devise?

I added Devise since I thought it should "handle users for me" but as it seems to be going everything I want besides the basics seems to be a hassle...

I already added the parameters, the thing is I can't find how to make it required... Or how to **easily** override the signup method and make the check myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, you should add to your model

validates_presence_of :username

(and in my case)

validates_uniqueness_of :username

that should make devise automatically validate and through errors if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"Out of the box" the Devise gem is very powerful, but when you start to step out of the box there is a significant amount of modification that has to be done to the underlying code.

I was a big user of devise when I first started using Rails. However in the last year I have found it easier to create my own authentication. Do a google search on 'rails authentication from scratch'. There are lots of good blog posts on the topic.

Building your own authentication is not terribly difficult, and gives you the flexibility to add whatever fields and customization you want. Additionally its lightweight (you only build what you need), and you are not exposed to the whims of gem updates and changes. Finally, you get the satisfaction of knowing you built it yourself.

Good luck!